# SimpleSAMLphp missing some configuration. What is missing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache2, simplesamlphp, amazon-elb

I am trying to use SimpleSAMLphp in AWS ubuntu instance but for some reason I can make it run correctly. I am using AWS-LoadBalancer for https, I do not know if it affect the configuration.

config.php

```
$config = array(
    'baseurlpath' => 'simplesaml/',
    'certdir' => 'cert/',
    'loggingdir' => 'log/',
    'datadir' => 'data/',
    'tempdir' => '/tmp/simplesaml',
    'technicalcontact_name' => 'David Pacheco',
    'technicalcontact_email' => 'dpacheco@lumstons.com',
    'timezone' => 'America/Mexico_City',
    'secretsalt' => '6ogT+0kPWJAO6FbKThWcI1spujbVVdmFEsPVRiPKEWw=',
    'auth.adminpassword' => 'david',
    'admin.protectindexpage' => false,
    'admin.protectmetadata' => false,
    'admin.checkforupdates' => true,
    'trusted.url.domains' => array(),
    'trusted.url.regex' => false,
    'enable.http_post' => false,
    'debug' => array(
        'saml' => false,
        'backtraces' => true,
        'validatexml' => false,
    ),
    'showerrors' => true,
    'errorreporting' => true,
    'logging.level' => SimpleSAML\Logger::NOTICE,
    'logging.handler' => 'syslog',
    'logging.facility' => defined('LOG_LOCAL5') ? constant('LOG_LOCAL5') : LOG_USER,
    'logging.processname' => 'simplesamlphp',
    'logging.logfile' => 'simplesamlphp.log',
    'statistics.out' => array(
    ),
    'proxy' => null,
    'database.dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=saml',
    'database.username' => 'simplesamlphp',
    'database.password' => 'secret',
    'database.options' => array(),
    'database.prefix' => '',
    'database.persistent' => false,
    'database.slaves' => array(
    ),
    'enable.saml20-idp' => false,
    'enable.shib13-idp' => false,
    'enable.adfs-idp' => false,
    'enable.wsfed-sp' => false,
    'enable.authmemcookie' => false,
    'default-wsfed-idp' => 'urn:federation:pingfederate:localhost',
    'shib13.signresponse' => true,
    'session.duration' => 8 * (60 * 60),
    'session.datastore.timeout' => (4 * 60 * 60),
    'session.state.timeout' => (60 * 60),
    'session.cookie.name' => 'SimpleSAMLSessionID',
    'session.cookie.lifetime' => 0,
    'session.cookie.path' => '/',
    'session.cookie.domain' => null,
    'session.cookie.secure' => false,
    'session.phpsession.cookiename' => 'SimpleSAML',
    'session.phpsession.savepath' => null,
    'session.phpsession.httponly' => true,
    'session.authtoken.cookiename' => 'SimpleSAMLAuthToken',
    'session.rememberme.enable' => false,
    'session.rememberme.checked' => false,
    'session.rememberme.lifetime' => (14 * 86400),
    'memcache_store.servers' => array(
        array(
            array('hostname' => 'localhost'),
        ),
    ),
    'memcache_store.prefix' => '',
    'memcache_store.expires' => 36 * (60 * 60),
    'language' => array(
        'priorities' => array(
            'no' => array('nb', 'nn', 'en', 'se'),
            'nb' => array('no', 'nn', 'en', 'se'),
            'nn' => array('no', 'nb', 'en', 'se'),
            'se' => array('nb', 'no', 'nn', 'en'),
        ),
    ),
    'language.available' => array(
        'en', 'no', 'nn', 'se', 'da', 'de', 'sv', 'fi', 'es', 'ca', 'fr', 'it', 'nl', 'lb', 
        'cs', 'sl', 'lt', 'hr', 'hu', 'pl', 'pt', 'pt-br', 'tr', 'ja', 'zh', 'zh-tw', 'ru',
        'et', 'he', 'id', 'sr', 'lv', 'ro', 'eu', 'el', 'af'
    ),
    'language.rtl' => array('ar', 'dv', 'fa', 'ur', 'he'),
    'language.default' => 'en',
    'language.parameter.name' => 'language',
    'language.parameter.setcookie' => true,
    'language.cookie.name' => 'language',
    'language.cookie.domain' => null,
    'language.cookie.path' => '/',
    'language.cookie.secure' => false,
    'language.cookie.httponly' => false,
    'language.cookie.lifetime' => (60 * 60 * 24 * 900),
    'language.i18n.backend' => 'SimpleSAMLphp',
    'attributes.extradictionary' => null,
    'theme.use' => 'default',
    'template.auto_reload' => false,
    'production' => true,
    'idpdisco.enableremember' => true,
    'idpdisco.rememberchecked' => true,
    'idpdisco.validate' => true,
    'idpdisco.extDiscoveryStorage' => null,
    'idpdisco.layout' => 'dropdown',
    'authproc.idp' => array(
        30 => 'core:LanguageAdaptor',

        45 => array(
            'class'         => 'core:StatisticsWithAttribute',
            'attributename' => 'realm',
            'type'          => 'saml20-idp-SSO',
        ),
        50 => 'core:AttributeLimit',
        99 => 'core:LanguageAdaptor',
    ),
    'authproc.sp' => array(
        90 => 'core:LanguageAdaptor',

    ),
    'metadata.sources' => array(
        array('type' => 'flatfile'),
    ),
    'metadata.sign.enable' => false,
    'metadata.sign.privatekey' => null,
    'metadata.sign.privatekey_pass' => null,
    'metadata.sign.certificate' => null,
    'metadata.sign.algorithm' => null,
    'store.type'                    => 'phpsession',
    'store.sql.dsn'                 => 'sqlite:/path/to/sqlitedatabase.sq3',
    'store.sql.username' => null,
    'store.sql.password' => null,
    'store.sql.prefix' => 'SimpleSAMLphp',
    'store.redis.host' => 'localhost',
    'store.redis.port' => 6379,
    'store.redis.prefix' => 'SimpleSAMLphp',
);
```

Apache 2 site config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName saml.veptec.mx
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    Alias /simplesaml /var/simplesamlphp/www

    <Directory /var/simplesamlphp/www>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The https://saml.dominian.com/simplesaml is redirected to https://saml.dominian.com/simplesaml/module.php/core/frontpage_welcome.php but that file return **HTTP ERROR 500**, I try to track down the error and I fond out that is problem with the config file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, the location it was not initializing. It was a bug.
In the ./lib/SimpleSAML/Locale/Localization.php file I only call this method:

```
$this->setupTranslator();
```

in the end of the constructor and it works correctly.